# Unable to toggle "enable java" in inspector html editor

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem Introduction**
Language version: Python 3.8
Operating system: Windows 10
Any other relevant software: Chrome web browser

Context:I am trying to follow along [with this tutorial.](https://youtu.be/5u391bX9FVE?t=1346)

Expected outcome: disabling java

Actual outcome and things I have already tried: The list I receive does not contain the option to toggle "enable java" after pressing "ctrl+shift+P".

Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. If you don't disable it, you can't enable it. Have you disabled it before looking for enable?

Comment: tags edited: java removed, javascript added.

Comment: @Phix I just realized that its not a matter of toggling enable, just selecting disable, thank you!

Comment: @rzwitserloot thank you, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is like JavaScript as Ham is like Hamster.

In other words, completely, utterly unrelated. Their names are by sheer coincidence* somewhat similar.

That video is saying **JavaScript**.

Java does not run in browsers; it runs on servers.

*) Actually, there is a bit of a link between the names, but, as far as the languages are concerned, guns v. grandmas.